# How to pass two options to tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox

Could someone kindly let me know how I can pass one option to `minted options` and one to `tcolorbox` at the same time to a `pythoncode` tcolorbox listing? I mean, I want some options get passed to `minted options`, as shown by `#1` in the MWE below and some get passed to `tcolorbox`, as shown by `#2`.

```
\documentclass{book}    
\usepackage[left=1.00in, right=1.00in, top=1.00in, bottom=1.00in]{geometry}    

\usepackage{amsmath}    
\usepackage{tcolorbox}    
\tcbuselibrary{minted,skins,breakable}    

\usepackage{hyperref}       
\hypersetup{ %    
    pdfborder = {0 0 0},    
    colorlinks=true,    
}    

\newtcblisting{pythoncode}[2][]{    
  listing engine=minted,    
  breakable,   
  colback=bg,    
  colframe=black!70,    
  listing only,    
  minted style=colorful,    
  minted language=python,    
  minted options={linenos=true,numbersep=3mm,texcl=true,#1},    
  left=5mm,enhanced,    
  overlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}\fill[black!25] (frame.south west)    
            rectangle ([xshift=5mm]frame.north west);\end{tcbclipinterior}},
            #2,
}    

\begin{document}    

\section{Python example}    
\begin{pythoncode}[colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,title=My nice heading]    
# indent your Python code to put into an email    
import glob    
# glob supports Unix style pathname extensions    
python_files = glob.glob('*.py')    
for file_name in sorted(python_files):    
    print '    ------' + file_name    

    with open(file_name) as f:    
        for line in f:    
            print '    ' + line.rstrip()    

    print    
\end{pythoncode}    

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you mean that some options (passed to the optional argument of your `pythoncode` environment) should be interpreted as `minted` options and others as `tcolorbox` options? If I guessed wrong, please clarify the question.

Comment: @Jubobs: Exactly. I explained it more in the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you did works with small changes. You have to pass options to `pythoncode` environment like this

```
\begin{pythoncode}[linenos=true,]{colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,title=My nice heading}
```

You have made the options to `tcolorbox` (i.e., `pythoncode`) mandatory hence they must be engulfed by braces where as the `minted` options go inside `brakets`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[left=1.00in, right=1.00in, top=1.00in, bottom=1.00in]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{minted,skins,breakable}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{ %
    pdfborder = {0 0 0},
    colorlinks=true,
}

\newtcblisting{pythoncode}[2][]{
  listing engine=minted,
  breakable,
  colback=bg,
  colframe=black!70,
  listing only,
  minted style=colorful,
  minted language=python,
  minted options={numbersep=3mm,texcl=true,#1},
  left=5mm,enhanced,
  overlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}\fill[black!25] (frame.south west)
            rectangle ([xshift=5mm]frame.north west);\end{tcbclipinterior}},
            #2,
}

\begin{document}

\section{Python example}
\begin{pythoncode}[linenos=true,]{colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,title=My nice heading}
# indent your Python code to put into an email
import glob
# glob supports Unix style pathname extensions
python_files = glob.glob('*.py')
for file_name in sorted(python_files):
    print '    ------' + file_name

    with open(file_name) as f:
        for line in f:
            print '    ' + line.rstrip()

    print
\end{pythoncode}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Some elaboration:

When you define

```
\newtcblisting{pythoncode}[2][]{
```

You are saying that there will be two arguments to the `pythoncode` environment. With an empty `[]`, you are making the first argument as `optional` whose default value is none. The optional argument is to be used within `brackets` or it can be simply omitted in which case the default value (here none) will be used. The second argument is mandatory and put inside braces. If you want to give no values to it simply use `{}` (unlike the first where you don't need to use any). Hence with no options you have to use

```
\begin{pythoncode}{}
```

Bottom line is `[2][]` means there are two arguments, first argument is optional and has default `none`.

Comment: Thank you. Can we make both optional not mandatory?

Comment: @Ahm easiest is to use `\begin{pythoncode}{}` if you don't want to give any options.

Comment: Thank you. I would be grateful if you could explain to me what `[2][]` does in `\newtcblisting{pythoncode}[2][]`. All I know is that I am defining two options but I dont know what the next empty bracket `[]` does.

Comment: @Ahm The empty brackets mean that the optional argument is taken as empty if you don't specify any. In other words `\begin{pythoncode}{...}` is equivalent to `\begin{pythoncode}[]{...}`.

Comment: I get the error `! Package minted Error: You must invoke LaTeX with the -shell-escape flag.`.

Comment: I worked out the issue with the flagging. However, this listing environment doesn't seem to be compatible with being inside a beamer slide.