# Minted Python example inside beamer frames

Tags: beamer, minted, python

I would like to include minted Python code examples in my Beamer slide decks. I found [an example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176174/how-to-pass-two-options-to-tcolorbox) that worked outside the `\frame` environment. Perhaps that will be suitable for future reports/documentation, but it doesn't serve my more specific
use case.

Inside my tex file I have the following:

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}

\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[totalframenumber]

%% Change shape of bullets
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[circle]
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[circle]
%%%

%% Import packages
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{ccicons}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,lined,commentsnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\tcbuselibrary{minted,skins,breakable}
%%%

\newtcblisting{pythoncode}[2][]{
  listing engine=minted,
  breakable,
  coltitle=UNBCGold,
  colback=black,
  colframe=UNBCGreen,
  listing only,
  minted style=colorful,
  minted language=python,
  minted options={numbersep=3mm,texcl=true,#1},
  left=5mm,enhanced,
  overlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}\fill[black!25] (frame.south west)
            rectangle ([xshift=5mm]frame.north west);\end{tcbclipinterior}},
            #2,
}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Premature Optimization}
    \begin{pythoncode}[linenos=true,]{title=Python Code Example}
    import glob
    \end{pythoncode}
\end{frame}
```

But I am getting an error: `! File ended while scanning use of \next.` This issue can be localized to the use of `pythoncode` due to the fact that taking it outside the `frame` scope allows compilation (with poor floating placement behaviour). Which is to say the following change compiles the PDF:

```
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Premature Optimization}
\end{frame}

\begin{pythoncode}[linenos=true,]{title=Python Code Example}
import glob
\end{pythoncode}
```

As suggested in the comments, I tried a `minted` `env` after importing the `minted` package. I found a similar pattern. The following didn't compile:

```
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Premature Optimization}
    \begin{tcolorbox}
    \begin{minted}{python}
    import glob
    \end{minted}
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{frame}
```

While moving the `minted` environment outside did compile (with undesirable placement of the tcolorbox):

```
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Premature Optimization}
\end{frame}

    \begin{tcolorbox}
    \begin{minted}{python}
    import glob
    \end{minted}
    \end{tcolorbox}
```

How can I construct a similar listing\tcolorobox around Python code examples that can exist within Beamer frames?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Did you try the `minted` package and a `minted` env?

Comment: @Archange I don't know the difference. I used `\tcbuselibrary{minted,skins,breakable}` among my imports.

Comment: @Archange Inside `\newtcblisting` I used `listing engine=minted`.

Comment: Thanks for extending your question and adding some example code, however your MWE does not compile (undefined colours, no `\begin{document}`, etc.). Anyway, I answered your question. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `[fragile]` for your frame:

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]
    \frametitle{Premature Optimization}
    \begin{pythoncode}[linenos=true,]{title=Python Code Example}
    import glob
    \end{pythoncode}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: I had so many errors pointing to the most ridiculous searches on google to find out this was the solution. Thanks.